# No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource error with json and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, cors

I use an API that is on a different server and i got an CORS error I think. The strange thing is that it first worked with no problem, then i got this error message

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php? tagmode=any&type=POST&format=jsonp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header   is present on the requested resource. Origin 'myadress.com' is   therefore not allowed acces
```

i added `crossDomain: "true"` and it worked for a day. Now it doesn't work again and i've searched and tried a lot of solutions i've found. But nothing works. What is the problem and how do i fix it? Tried `jsonp` instead of `json` with and without `type:post` and the &callback=? does nothing. I've even installed the CORS enable extension for chrome. But alwways the same error, I have no control over the API itself or the server hosting it. How can I fix this? Below is my code.

```
        function random() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php", {
                tagmode: "any",
                type: "POST",
                format: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: "true"
            }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                var result = "";
                $.each(data.drinks, function (index, value) {
                    result += "<p>" + value.idDrink + "<p>";
                    result += "<p>" + value.strDrink + "<p>";
                });
                $('#result').html(result);
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: The site does not set the headers so there is nothing you can do from your end. Severside proxy is what you would need.

Comment: The server doesn't return jsonp BUT json. You should then use your own server to proxify the request

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right you are doing an `AJAX call` to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is Using [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

> Regular web pages can use the `XMLHttpRequest` object to send and
>   receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same
>   origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to
>   remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests
>   cross-origin permissions.

**Solution :**

For allowing access to specific domain only:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.thecocktaildb.com");
```

Check this [blog post](http://john.sh/blog/2011/6/30/cross-domain-ajax-expressjs-and-access-control-allow-origin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make some modification for bypass CORS error. but target environment can also block CORS request. When I used Paypal checkout, I encountered same problem. Paypal environment doesn't accept CORS request.

So that you can try to make this call over server side.